# Creating a login controller for two or more user

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have created a login page in Visualforce. I have also created a controller related to it. Now I can log in with one user saved in my database. But I want not one user but two or more user can log in...
 Here is my controller..

```
public class CustomLoginController 
{
    public String username{get; set;}
    public String password{get; set;}
    public Logistic__c Llog{get; set;}


    public PageReference dologin()
    {
         if(username!=null && password!=null )
         {
             Llog = [select id, User_Name__c,Password__c from Logistic__c];


             if(username == Llog.User_Name__c && password == Llog.Password__c)
             {
                 Pagereference ref = Page.Logistic_work;
                    ref.setredirect(true);
                    return ref;
             }

            else
                {
                    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO, 'TRY AGAIN... .'));
                 return null ;
            }
         }

        else
        {
             ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO, '... .'));
             return null;
        }

    }
}
```

Here is my database
[image: user details of logistics object]

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct and it will work for n number of users. You just need to create separate records for them. Also you can modify your query to get better results.

```
public PageReference dologin()
    {
         if(username!=null && password!=null )
         {
             List<Logistic__c> LlogList = [select id, User_Name__c,Password__c from Logistic__c WHERE User_Name__c =: username and Password__c =: password];


             if(LlogList.size() > 0)
             {
                 Llog = LlogList[0];
                 Pagereference ref = Page.Logistic_work;
                    ref.setredirect(true);
                    return ref;
             }

            else
                {
                    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO, 'TRY AGAIN... .'));
                 return null ;
            }
         }

        else
        {
             ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO, '... .'));
             return null;
        }

    }
```

Although you need to make sure username is unique.